# The Canonical Embedding of X into X**, Norm Density of J(X) in X**

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X $ be a Banach space and let $ J : X \to X^{**} $ be the canonical embedding of $ X $ into $ X^{**} $.  It is known that $ J(X) $ is weak* dense in $ X^{**} $.

Are there any known conditions on $ X $ for which $ J(X) $ is norm dense in $ X^{**} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $J:X\to X^{**}$ is an isometry, so $J(X)$ is always a norm-closed subspace of $X^{**}$.  When $J(X)=X^{**}$, we say that $X$ is a reflexive space.  There are several results describing when $X$ is reflexive, the most prominent being that $X$ is reflexive iff normed closed and bounded subsets of $X$ are weakly compact.

Comment: If $X^{**}$ is larger than $J(X)$ is there a way to construct one of its new elements ?

Comment: Ah yes, I am aware if $ X $ is reflexive then $ J(X) $ is (trivially) norm dense in $ X** $ since $ J(X) $ is all of $ X** $.  Are there any other known conditions on non-reflexive $ X $ such that $ J(X) $ is norm dense in $ X** $?  (Pardon my poor latex in formatting this).  Thanks!

Comment: @reuns In generality, I don't believe so.  Some constructions depend on the axiom of choice (see for example [Banach limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit)), while others can be explicitly constructed (see for example [James' space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_space)).

Comment: @LMW As I stated, $J(X)$ is norm-closed in $X^{**}$.  So either $J(X)=X^{**}$, or it is not dense.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  That completely flew over me.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help